# Optimizing network throughput between CloudSQL and CloudRun instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

Consider the following setup on Google Cloud Platform:

- a CloudSQL instance with 4 TiB SSD, 20 vCPUs, 150 GiBs RAM with a Private IP
- a 50 GiB MySQL table which (obviously) fits into RAM (consider it to be warm and already in RAM)
- a VPC Network and a Serverless VPC connector for it with 2 machines of e2-standard-4 type
- a Cloud Run instance with 8 vCPUs and 32 GiB RAM running NodeJS using the Serverless connector
- all resources are in the same region

We are trying to use the Cloud Run instance to process a big portion of the MySQL table, save the result somewhere and exit at the end. We would like to get a really high transfer speed between MySQL and Cloud Run.

As Google states [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/network-bandwidth) the maximum egress throughput per vCPU is 2 Gpbs:

> Per-VM maximum egress bandwidth is generally 2 Gbps per vCPU ...

but maximum per vCPU throughput we could get was around 400 Mbps when using a single Cloud Run instance reading a simple `select * from ... limit N` using `node/mysql2` with streams. Take into account that the table was already pre-loaded into RAM, so disk should not bother us, I guess, but 1/5 of the maximum throughput seems quite low in my opinion.

Do you know what could cause such a low throughput limit or how could it be debugged?

Some side notes:

- We written a PoC in Go to read from MySQL an we achieved slightly better results, about +50 Mbps
- If Cloud Run or Cloud SQL is not suitable for our use-case, I am open to suggestion, but we used what was the simplest deploy option
- If we spawn multiple instances of Cloud Run we achieve total egress throughputs from MySQL and through the VPC connector of more than 10 Gbps which makes me to think that the problem is the Cloud Run instance
- Unfortunately, our problem is not easily scalable on the horizontal, so spawning multiple instances does not solve our use-case, we would like to achieve higher per-instance speeds

Comment: The doc you share about 2Gbps per vCPU is for VMs in Compute Engine which applies to the connector but not sure if Cloud Run can use all that bandwidth.

Comment: ***was around 400 Mbps***. That is excellent performance for a serverless container. If you need higher performance, launch a Compute Engine instance. Remember, raw network performance is the theoretical ceiling. The database must have time to interpret your SQL request and process result sets. In the real world, a database delivering a constant 40 Megabytes per second is excellent.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide performance enhancing suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Upon checking this concern it was mentioned on this [documentaiton](https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas#cloud_run_bandwidth_limits) that Maximum bytes per instance = 75 megabytes per second (MBps) and Maximum total packet rate per instance = 64,000 packets per second are the bandwidth limit based on the sum of ingress and egress.

You can check with GCP [Sales Team](https://cloud.google.com/contact) if this is possible for quota increase if the bandwidth mentioned from the link is still not enough.